# Different element height on Windows Phone 8. Phonegap

Tags: css, cordova, windows-phone-8

I've got a problem with setting right height to my element.

The problem is, on Android and iOS it works fine (element has 80px in height), but on WP8 it magically gets 110px height.

HTML:

```
<header go-click="/mainmenu">
     <div class="logo"></div>
     <button class="menu" ng-if="loaded"></button>
</header>
```

SCSS:

```
& > header
  {
    $headerHeight: 80px;
    $headerPadding: 16px;

    @include box-sizing(border-box);
    @include flex(0, 0, $headerHeight);
    @include flexbox(row, space-between);

    padding: $headerPadding;
    background-color: #ffffff;

    & > .logo
    {
      width: 130px;
      height: 48px;
      background: url("../images/logo.png") center center no-repeat;
      background-size: 130px 48px;
    }

    & > .menu
    {
      margin-top: $headerHeight / 2 - 10px - $headerPadding;
      width: 26px;
      height: 20px;
      background: url("../images/menu.png") center center no-repeat;
      background-size: 26px 20px;
      border: none;
    }
  }
```

Is there any well-known bug in WP8 that has a workaround? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you using `box-sizing: border-box`?

Comment: Yep, there is `@include box-sizing(border-box)` mixin from Compass

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that. WP8 must not be using box-sizing correctly. Maybe try removing that and subtracting the padding from the height to see if that gives you consistent results.